# Want to change JSON Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have this class

```
public class Contact {
     #regionContact Info
     public Guid ContactID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string RegID { get; set; }
     public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
     public string Tel { get; set; }
     #endregion 
}
```

when I call getAllContact() method, I get this result

```
[{"ContactID":"7abe6291-43f2-e411-b150-000c2975315f","Name":"Visitor 1","RegID":"1","MobileNumber":"1122334455","Tel":"1122334455"},{"ContactID":"f76f310f-a3f3-e411-b150-000c2975315f","Name":"Visitor 2","RegID":"2","MobileNumber":null,"Tel":null},{"ContactID":"9b3e6018-a3f3-e411-b150-000c2975315f","Name":"Visitor 3","RegID":"3","MobileNumber":null,"Tel":null}]
```

but what I want is with this kind of format.

```
{"contacts":[{"ContactID":"7abe6291-43f2-e411-b150-000c2975315f","Name":"Visitor 1","RegID":"1","MobileNumber":"1122334455","Tel":"1122334455"},{"ContactID":"f76f310f-a3f3-e411-b150-000c2975315f","Name":"Visitor 2","RegID":"2","MobileNumber":null,"Tel":null},{"ContactID":"9b3e6018-a3f3-e411-b150-000c2975315f","Name":"Visitor 3","RegID":"3","MobileNumber":null,"Tel":null}]}
```

How can I change to get this json format? Could anybody help me please?

Comment: What is the return type of ```getAllContact()``` ?

Comment: List<Contact> getAllContact()

Comment: And that becomes a JSON array. It seems that you simply want to take the array R, and return {"contacts":R}, correct? What are you using for your JSON parsing/creating?

Comment: I think it has returned the correct result, I mean is there any particular reason why you need "contacts" in front of the json string? How do you gonna process it?

Comment: @MartinDavidValentinoSiagian  I need to fetch that json array from iOS app. In iOS app, I need title ("contacts") to fetch it.

Comment: If so, then you can follow Steve's answer by creating a new class with ```contact``` as properties name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getAllContact() method should an object with one parameter in it called contacts which is of type List

```
public class ContactList {
    public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Then serialise the ContactList object.

Comment: so do I need to add one more new class?

Comment: If you want it to look like the JSON you gave, then yes; you'll need it to give the name to the array.

Comment: So to clarify: your current method is returning a `List<Contact>`, which serialises to an array: `[{...}, {...}]`. This essentially wraps that list in another objects with a property contacts, such that it serialises as `{contacts:[{...},{...}]}`. So change your `getAllContacts()` method to return an instance of the `ContactList` class with the `contacts` property initialised appropriately.

Comment: @Luke , Yup, Thank u too :D

Comment: No problem, champ. Let us know if you run into anymore trouble; noone has quite given you complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write like this way . sure u will get your result.Here i have added one item in list. you can add multiple items.

```
   void getAllContact()
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<Contact>> contactsDic = new Dictionary<string, List<Contact>>();
            List<Contact> list = new List<Contact>();

            list.Add(new Contact
            {
                ContactID = Guid.Parse("7abe6291-43f2-e411-b150-000c2975315f"),
                Name = "Visitor 1",
                RegID = "1",
                MobileNumber = "1122334455",
                Tel = "1122334455"
            }
            );
            contactsDic.Add("contacts", list);

            string ss = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contactsDic);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , Kashif :D. I created new class with List<Contact> variable. It's quite cool. Problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

If your model is Contact class so Simplify do this:

```
return Ok(new {contacts = yourmodel});
```